# R function with strict Arguments

Tags: r

How to write R functions with strict arguments, meaning without getting argument as defined in definition it will fail,  no matter weather that argument is used in function or not.

I had written following code where I defined input argument in definition but able to call without passing arguments

```
hello<- function(name){
    a<- 100
    print("welcome")
    if (a == 10){print(name)}else{print("bad")}
}
hello()
```

Is there ay way where I can make input argument strictly mandatory else will give error at function call

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `R` only throws an error for missing argument if you actually use the argument. `R` provides the `missing(arg)` function that returns `TRUE` if the parameter `arg` is missing in the function call.
You can chain this with the R-equivalent of `assert`, which is `stopifnot()`.

You want to abort if `missing(name)` returns TRUE. So we invert the statement with the `!` operator for `stopifnot()`, leading to the following example code:

```
hello<- function(name){
    stopifnot(!missing(name))

    # rest of the function:
    a<- 100
    print("welcome")
    if (a == 10){print(name)}else{print("bad")}
}
```

If you want the error message to be more descriptive, you can use an if-statement with `stop` to provide a custom error message:

```
hello<- function(name){  
  if (missing(name)){
    stop("YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE HERE.")
  }
  
  # rest of the function:
  a<- 100
  print("welcome")
  if (a == 10){print(name)}else{print("bad")}
}
```

Comment: This also works:  `stopifnot("YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE HERE." = !missing(name))`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `missing()` is defining the default value as `NULL` and then check `is.null()` at the start of the function:

```
hello <- function(name = NULL) {
  if (is.null(name)) stop("Argument name missing")  
  print("welcome")
  print(name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`force()` will force the argument to be evaluated, which throws an error if it is missing.

```
hello <- function(name)
{
    force(name)
    # ...
}
```